# some smartphones pick up the desktop media queries?

Tags: android, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

We recently developed a website that essentially has 2 modes, mobile and a tablet + desktop one. The css file is laid out with mobile rules first, then there is a breakpoint for any sizes above 640px, so we could show the desktop version to the 7" tablets when on landspace.

However, although it is working great for all iphones, my galaxy s4, even the windows phone and of course for the ipad and desktop, some mobile phones pick up the desktop styles, essentially showing the desktop version, namely the galaxy s2 and the galaxy s3 among others.

As i said, my css code is built mobile first, so all mobiles with a width of less than 640px (pretty much all) should not pick up the desktop styles, the media query is as follows:

```
@media all and (min-width: 641px) { .... }
```

So i do not really understand why.. any ideas?

edit: I forgot to add we have added a conditional that will check whether the size of the device is larger than 640, in which case it sets the viewport size to the full width of the website so it scales down on tablets, or else it just sets it to device-width.

```
<meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
if (screen.width > 640) {
    var mvp = document.getElementById('testViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content','width=1000');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input, i found the problem.

Some android versions have a bug where the viewport will not report correctly when the page loads, i was getting 800px viewport sizes reported for galaxy 1, 2 and 3 (!!!). The issue was fixed by adding a timeout of 200ms before actually checking the viewport width, it seems this small delay is good enough for the device to report back the right size.
It creates a small window of time (the 200ms) where the scaling of the desktop version is visible, but at least it solves the issue.

solution for anyone landing here having the same issue:

```
<meta id="testViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 640) {
            var mvp = document.getElementById('testViewport');
            mvp.setAttribute('content','width=1000');
        }
    }, 200);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I search for Galaxy S3 Media Queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .your-css{}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .your-css{}
}
```

Looks like thats what it actually looks for....You can try scaling it by changing viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Also, You can add jquery to change sizes....Jquery:

```
 // Check for device screen size
 if($.mobile.media("screen and (max-device-width: 640px)")) {
  // Change viewport for smaller devices
 $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

**Also:**

You can go open this in your s3 so you can get accuracy for your Galaxy media queries:

http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/css-media-queries/test-features.html

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. However that was not the issue, as mobile devices report a mobile viewport size, which for the S3 is actually 360x640.